# I'm creating a 2D array in Javascript. How do I skip creating a part of it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

What I'm doing:
I need to create a ~400x400 grid of waypoints. I have the coordinates. Each waypoint is 9 blocks from the previous. Each waypoint is its own file.

The issue:
There's a ~100x100 hole in the grid. Those waypoints should not be created.
I divided the issue into 4 rectangles and created loops for each of them. It works, but it's an ugly solution. Someday, it might have to do be for something more serious than a game and could me more complex than this.

**How do I do it in one loop?** The solution probably lies in using some AND or NOT while declaring the loops. Please, advise.

There might also be a different approach to the problem. A different solution I hadn't thought of. Feel free to suggest.

Here's the code up to the first loop. The other three are practically copy-paste.

```
fs = require('fs');

const xWest = -7113;
const xEast = -6744;
const zNorth = -10265;
const zSouth = -9896;
const wallxWest = -6993;
const wallxEast = -6864;
const wallzNorth = -10145;
const wallzSouth = -10016;

var currentX = 0;
var currentZ = 0;

//The first loop:
for (currentX = xWest; 
    currentX < wallxWest; 
    currentX = currentX + 9) 
    {
        for (currentZ = zNorth; 
            currentZ < zSouth; 
            currentZ = currentZ + 9) {
              fs.writeFile(`...${currentX-xWest}_${currentZ-zNorth}.json`,
              `file_contents_here`
              ,function (err){if (err) return console.log(err);
              });
    }};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. That "different approach" part.

1. create an array in the code and set the middle to an unused value
2. for each non-unused value, make a file.

Edit: fixed the original code. Wrapped "write file" in an "if within range".

```
for (currentX = xWest+4;
  currentX < xEast+4;
  currentX = currentX + 9) {
  for (currentZ = zNorth+4;
    currentZ < zSouth+4;
    currentZ = currentZ + 9) {
      if (
        ((currentX < wallxWest) || (currentX > wallxEast)) && ((currentZ < wallzNorth) || (currentZ > wallzSouth)))
      {
      fs.writeFile(`...${currentX - 4 - xWest}_${currentZ - 4 - zNorth}.json`,
      //file contents removed for code readability
      , function (err) { if (err) return console.log(err); });
    }
  }
};
```